# In the R language, if the row name of rhandsontable is long, it will be displayed only partially on the screen

Tags: r, rhandsontable

In the R language, if the line name of rhandsontable is long, it will be displayed only partially on the screen.
I am trying to use rhandsontable in R language.
I want to give long names to rows of tables made with rhandsontable.
However, if I give long name to the table row name, it will only be displayed on the screen halfway.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIzLm.png)

```
library(rhandsontable)
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(1:2), x2 = c(3:4))
rownames(df) <- c("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")
rhandsontable(df)
```

Even if the table row name is long, how can I make it all appear on the screen in rhandsontable?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem with the rowHeaderWidth option.
The code is described below.

```
library(rhandsontable)
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(1:2), x2 = c(3:4))
rownames(df) <- c("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")
rhandsontable(df, rowHeaderWidth = 200)
```